Blender 4.2 weird shading
I´ve modeled a bottle, and I've tried to do everything with proper extrudes and edge loops, I can't see any double vertices or overlapping faces or anything that explains that weird shading:




can you please upload the bottle as a file?

@Chris here's the download link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZeLLC-Ya9c-l2iBfyYU6qPgWicXqyFEZ/view?usp=drive_link

That Google Drive file link is requesting access so we can't download it.  So that it will be available to users reading your question in future you should share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

done, thanks for the tip @JohnEason

I'm not sure how they got there, but if you go to the ObjectData (green triangle icon) section of your object properties, open the Geometry Data section and click Clear Custom Split Normals Data that will get rid of your shading problem.



Amazing! Thanks! Dumb question..what are those split normals? What does it mean and what's usually the purpose?

This is the Blender manual section on Custom Split Normals. You should really read the whole 'Structure' section to get an overall view of meshes and normals and there's a YT video about them here.
